# Unable to assign the value of selected row to a variable

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableView controller that is pulling data from JSON, the table contains sections and row data using the following structure:

```
import UIKit

struct Section {
    let name : String
    let items : [Portfolios]
}
```

Comment: Where you fill structure array?

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: You are not filling 'structure' anywhere in fetchJSON()

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be done, currently, fetchJSON is grouping all `person` into sections. Is it possible to fill structure?

Comment: You might forgot adding data in 'structure' array. where you declare structure? it's class level? please show did select methods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably forgot to respecify the value of structure in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Therefore please change your tableView's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method to:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Add this line
    structure = sections[indexPath.section].items


    let theStructure = structure[indexPath.row]
    codeSelected = theStructure.code


    // ... code selected must have taken the correct value

}
```